# How to access a class function from another class using an object pointer in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have two classes Pixel and Grid. Pixel keeps a reference to the Grid via a pointer. I'm trying to access the functions of Grid using the Grid pointer. I've got it compiling and running, but it returns the wrong result.

The following is the Header for my Grid class:

```
#ifndef GRID_H
#define GRID_H
#include <FastLED.h>

//-- GRID SETUP --//
#define GRID_X 8            //The height of the Grid
#define GRID_Y 8            //The width of the Grid

//--- MEMBER FUNCTION ACCESS ---//
#define CALL_MEMBER_FN(object, ptrToMember) ((object).*(ptrToMember))

class Grid
{
  private:
    CRGB *leds;
    uint16_t num_leds;
    uint8_t data_pin;
    uint8_t height;
    uint8_t width;

  public:
    //-----CONSTRUCTOR-----//
    Grid();

    //-----GETTER------//
    virtual uint16_t getNumLeds();
    String getLedType();
    CRGB* getLeds();
    uint8_t getHeight();
    uint8_t getWidth();

    //-----CHECKS-----//

    //-----OTHER FUNCTIONS-----//
    void show();
    void clear();
};

typedef uint8_t (Grid::*gridFnPtr_UINT)();   //This is to be able to access getHeight/getWidth member functions from a pointer outside the class
typedef CRGB* (Grid::*gridFnPtr_CRGB)();     //This is to be able to access getLeds member function from a pointer outside the class.
```

This is the constructor for the Grid Class placed in Grid.cpp

```
Grid::Grid()
{
  //Construct the GRID for our FASTLED based Matrix Display
  num_leds = NUM_LEDS;
  data_pin = DATA_PIN;
  height = GRID_X;
  width = GRID_Y;

  leds = malloc(num_leds*sizeof(CRGB));

  FastLED.addLeds<LED_TYPE, DATA_PIN, COLOR_ORDER>(leds, NUM_LEDS);                       //Setup our LED Matrix using the FastLED initializer
}
```

From what I've read, I've implemented a type definition for a function pointer with the same returns as the function I'm trying to reference. Then I set up a macro in order to be able to call the function using the function pointer and an object.

This is how I'm trying to call it withing one of my functions in my Pixel class

```
//---LED FUNCTIONS ---//
void Pixel::set(uint8_t _r, uint8_t _g, uint8_t _b)
{

  uint8_t index = resolve(x, y);
  Serial.print("Index: ");
  Serial.print(index, DEC);
  Serial.print("\n");
  gridFnPtr_UINT g_width = &Grid::getWidth;
  gridFnPtr_UINT g_height = &Grid::getHeight;
  gridFnPtr_CRGB g_leds = &Grid::getLeds;


  uint8_t width = CALL_MEMBER_FN(*grid, g_height)();
  uint8_t height = CALL_MEMBER_FN(*grid, g_width)();

  Serial.println("Grid Width: ");
  Serial.println(width, DEC);
  Serial.println("Grid Height: ");
  Serial.println(height, DEC);

  CRGB* leds = CALL_MEMBER_FN(*grid, g_leds)();
  leds[index] = CRGB(_r, _g, _b);
}
```

This code runs, but returns the wrong result. In regards to getHeight() and getWidth(), they should return 8 and 8 respectively, but return 0 and 1 right now. The end goal is to be able to set the leds[] array in the Grid Class using the Grid pointer I have kept reference of. I'm not sure what I've done wrong, or what I've misunderstood, so could someone point me in the right direction and explain the error as simply and clearly as possible?

Comment: Using lambdas and `std::function` might be much more convenient for you than dealing with raw function pointers.

Comment: Where do you set those variables to `8`?

Comment: "_Pixel keeps a reference to the Grid via a pointer_" - that sounds highly inefficient. Why not let a `Grid`be a number of `Pixel`s?

Comment: Taking another look at the code: Why do you need function pointers anyways? Can't you just invoke `grid->getWidth()` ?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings It's in the #define above the Grid class

Comment: @TedLyngmo , perhaps I need to try and organize my classes better. I'm not sure exactly how to structure it. I'm trying to turn an arduino project I've made incorporating the FASTLED library for controlling a LED strip, or in this case an LED Matrix into something more OO and organized. Right now It's just 1250 lines of code all clumped together into one file which isn't exactly what I want. I spent 3 weeks thinking that I had to code in C, then realized I could code in C++.

Comment: @NahinJumaEdmonds Those macros aren't used anywhere in the code.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, they are used inside the Constructor for Grid. Sorry, I can add that if it's helpful.

Comment: @NahinJumaEdmonds A pixel is usually a very basic type with no overhead, like pointers/references to anything. Let the container manage the pixels.

Comment: Your question should contain a [mcve] so we can rule out unrelated errors that you've hidden. Make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: The first thing I would try to rule out as a cause is that `CALL_MEMBER_FN` macro. *Macros are vicious and will rip your code to shreds if given the chance (i.e. not used carefully).* Replace each use of that macro with what you think the preprocessor would replace it with. See if the error comes from the macro or from something else. I'd also reduce the example to focus on one aspect, such as keeping "width" and dropping "height", "leds", and "data pin".